# Dynamic List Values

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Dictionary<string, EmployeeInfo> employeeInfoList = new Dictionary<string, EmployeeInfo>();

employeeInfoList = EmployeeInfoProxy.GetAllEmployeeInfo(TenantId);

if (employeeInfoList != null)
{
    List<EmployeeInfo> employee = new List<EmployeeInfo>(employeeInfoList.Values);

    ViewData["Name"] = employee[0].Name; 
    ViewData["Salary"] = employee[0].Salary;
    ViewData["Department"] = employee[0].Department;
    ViewData["Designation"] = employee[0].Designation;
    ViewData["Address"] = employee[0].Address;
    ViewData["Address1"] = employee[0].Address1;
}
```

the above code is working fine.if the employee has only one record,so i had hardcoded  `employee[0]`.

if there are more rows,how to pass those index to employee(for eg employee[\i should get the value dynamically here].

Comment: Its always better to surround your piece of code with code tag by highligthing the code and pressing 101010. Now regarding your question you could through your employeeInfoList. if you dont know how to do this please following this http://dotnetperls.com/dictionary-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, given a List you could use linq to grab a single employee.

```
EmployeeInfo singleEmployee = employee.Where( x => x.Id).SingleOrDefault();
if (singleEmployee != null)
{
   do something here
}
```

that said, I don't know if you have a 'key' against the employee like Id or similar.

To get by index, you have a bigger round trip (outputting the emploees to a grid or something similar, allowing a click that passes in the index of the employee you want, and access the single eployee that way).

Unless you're heavily employing caching in the 'EmployeeInfoProxy.GetAllEmployeeInfo()' method though, I'd say you want a 'GetEmployeeInfoById()' and again, I'll harp back to the need for your EmployeeInfo to have a unique Id of some description - you will make your life so much easier.

Hope this helps.
Cheers,
Terry

[in addition]
if employeeListInfo has 3 entries, then to access each of them I'd say the best way would be to create a viewmodel (it looks like this is MVC), but worst case scenario you could do:

```
List<EmployeeInfo> employee = new List<EmployeeInfo>(employeeInfoList.Values);

ViewData["Employees"] = employee;
```

then in your view, just do:

```
<% foreach(EmployeeInfo employeeDetails in ViewData["Employees"] as List<EmployeeInfo>) { %>
   <!-- you will be looping through each employee here, so you can do as you wish
<% } %>
```

I wouldn't say this is best practice - using a ViewModel would likely represent a better way to do this, though the above will certainly give you a solution that will work in your case.

Comment: in that employeeInfoList i am returning three count employeeInfoList = EmployeeInfoProxy.GetAllEmployeeInfo(TenantId); but it display only first record how to do dyanamic?